# validate xml tags, that are not enclosed within root tag

Tags: java, xml

I have some XML tags in a String(xmlStr) like this:

```
<mainTag1>
    <tagA>lyrics</tagA>
    <tagB>com.example.action.Lyrics</tagB>
</mainTag1>
<mainTag2>
    <tagC>lyrics</tagC>
    <tagD>/lyrics</tagD>
</mainTag2>
```

I am validating this XML with the below code:

```
final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStr.getBytes());
final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document document = docBuilder.parse(inputStream);
```

the docBuilde.parse, throws an exception:

> The markup in the document following the root element must be
>   well-formed.

For my code requirement I cannot add any root tag. Is there any way to validate my tags, without getting this error?

Comment: Its an invalid XML if it doesn't contain a root tag.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your string with an element before you parse it? (`"<doc>"+xmlStr+"</doc>"`) Does this violate your "For my code requirement I cannot add any root tag." condition?

Comment: add a root tag, validate, then (for whichever reaspn) remove the root tag

Comment: ...another vote for programmatically inserting a root tag before parsing.

Comment: And if it's a long string and you want to avoid the cost of copying it, you can reference it in an entity reference from another document, and validate it that way.